# Horizontally join datasets in Pyarrow with hierarchical column names

Tags: pyarrow

I have N parquet files from different data sources, each of which is row-indexed by time. Each file has the same column schema.  I would like to join them horizontally into a single Pyarrow dataset with nested column names (i.e. `(file1, col1) ... (file1, colM), (file2, col1)...` ).  This seems to be tricky in Pyarrow.  I'm able to use Pandas to change the column index and join them, but I wanted to see if anyone had some guidance on how to do it directly in Pyarrow, particularly to be able to use the `dataset.to_batches()` calls on the combined data. I could translate to pandas and back to solve the problem, which is why I'm asking here for a more direct and efficient (and hopefully simple) way to do it.

Here's the pandas solution, which is admittedly simple:

```
frames = [pd.read_parquet(filename) for filename in filenames]
return pd.concat(frames, axis=1, keys=segment_names, join='outer')
```

Comment: I also tried overriding the schema in each Pyarrow dataset (using replace_schema). The new schema should be structurally compatible, but changing the field names means that the column data is no longer accessible.

Comment: Does each file have the exact same number of rows?  Are the timestamp indices of the files identical?  Or would you need to do a database style join to match rows with the same timestamp?

Comment: No, they will generally overlap but it's not guaranteed. That's a big part of the problem - pandas does this well, but I was hoping to find a pure pyarrow solution.

Comment: Maybe my best option might be to see how pandas manages it under the hood. It uses pyarrow as a backend for loading parquet files.